# Jwt Token Problems

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, jwt

ı want to do authorize in my mvc app ı have swagger api and ı m using api method Auth/Login and ı have JWT token key but ı can authorize  what ı miss.

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
        {
            
            var response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("Auth/Login",loginViewModel);
            
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //var body =await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<LoginResponse>();
                var body=await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
               

                LoginResponse loginResponse=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponse>(body);
                var token = loginResponse.Token;
               
               
               
 var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");

            }
            return View("Index",loginViewModel);
          
        }
```

here is my mvc login code and my Dashboar auth code

```
[Authorize]
    public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
     
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        }
```

thaks for helping

Comment: Can you explain what is going wrong? Do you get errors or are you missing something?

Comment: I am getting HTTP401 error

Comment: I have token in my token variable and I can’t login there is a HTTPS 401 authorize error probably I am missing return my token but how can I? I you want I can send my web api auth/Login code